# Replacing missing values in sqlite tables

Tags: sqlite

I have a table which I created in sqlite that looks like this:

```
  Age   Height
   12     186
          175
          169
   13
   15     171
```

I want to replace the missing values in each column with its column mean. I have used the update  function but there does not seem to be any visible update in the table. Say the table above is called test, I did this already

```
UPDATE test SET Age=13.3 WHERE Age IS NULL;

UPDATE test SET Height=175.25 WHERE Height IS NULL;
```

Also, I would like to know how I can incorporate the mean automatically with a select statement without having to manually input it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the missing values are not NULL but some other value, probably an empty string.
You should fix that:

```
UPDATE test SET Age    = NULL WHERE Age    = '';
UPDATE test SET Height = NULL WHERE Height = '';
```

To compute the average value of a set of values, use the AVG aggregate function:

```
UPDATE test SET Age    = (SELECT AVG(Age)    FROM test) WHERE Age    IS NULL;
UPDATE test SET Height = (SELECT AVG(Height) FROM test) WHERE Height IS NULL;
```

(AVG will ignore NULL values, but count other invalid values as a zero value, so it is important that missing entries actually are NULL.)

Comment: Is it possible by any chance to combine the 2 statements into 1 and avoid calling the column names? This is because incase I have so many variables in the table and would like to replace missing values, more like automatation.

Comment: That would be horribly complex.